# C# using statement cache

Tags: c#, caching, using

It must be a very dump question but I am wondering if I can use a cached object as part of the using statement
e.g

```
using(Class1 sample = Cache.GetClass<Class1>())
```

Cache.class is a **static** class which uses **memoryCache** to store a copy of Class1, and the GetClass is to get a copy of the stored object from cache if it is already there.

In my real life (almost, but simpilfied) exmaple, I have got this:

```
using (dataDesignerClass dds = Cache.GetClass<dataDesignerClass>()){
   ...
   Dataset ds = new Dataset();
   dds.dataadapter1.fill(ds); //dds is the data designer which contains all the sqlconnection, sql commands, adapters..etc which can get quite big
   ...
}
```

..which seems to be ok to me, but I find that **SOMETIMES** the dataset (ds) is not filled by the dataadapter1, without returning error.

My GetClass static class:

```
 public static T GetClass<T> () where T: class
        {
            string keyName = "CACHE_" + typeof(T).Name.ToUpper();
            CacheItem cacheItem = null;

            cacheItem = GetCache(keyName); //a function to return the cache item
            if (cacheItem == null)
            {
                T daClass = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) as T;  //the constructor will call the initilalization routine        
                AddCache(keyName, daClass);
                return daClass;
            }
            return (T)cacheItem.Value;            
        }
```

Can someone explain why it fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reusing a shared object is sometimes good practice, but you need to make sure it can be reused. In your program, you are storing a data adapter in the cache and trying to reuse it between different threads, that causes strange results sometimes because the data adapter can't be shared. Imaging two threads get a same instance of your adapter and modify it at the same time! IMO the data adapter is quite lite and you can create a new instance for each db read, it's unnecessary to cache and reuse it, that makes things complex.

Comment: Please refer to the comments above.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @WML If your adapter is a normal property in the template, you still have the bug I mentioned in my answer. Because the template is shared, the adapter will also be shared.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a bad idea to use `using` on something you cache.

The idea behind `using` is that it disposes all unmanaged memory allocation and handles an object has before it is destructed. You should not use your object after it is disposed. The problem here is it is not your intention to destruct and get rid of the object, hence you save it in a cache!

Also, a `DataReader` is somewhat of a cursor typed object. It will not like you for reusing it, especially when you use more than one thread.

Disposing the object will most likely break your software and give unexpected and unwanted result. Don't use `using` in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks. I made a mistake in posting the question. My intention was to be able to cache a 'template' of a data designer class (with all the sql connections, adapters, heaps of sqlcommands and parameters...) so it does not need to go through the class instantiation routine when using NEW.  I understand 'Using' statement is not a good way to go.